# How to mint 3d model (.glb file) with metadata

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js, ipfs, nft

How can i mint 3d model in blockchain with metadata.Model is minted successfully and its showing in my wallet.
for generating metadata i am using NFT.storage.Code is working fine when i mint image but having trouble whenever i upload .glb fie

Error: property `image` must be a Blob or File object

my contract code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract Minty is ERC721 {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor(string memory tokenName, string memory symbol) ERC721(tokenName, symbol) {
        _setBaseURI("ipfs://");
    }

    function mintToken(address owner, string memory metadataURI)
    public
    returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 id = _tokenIds.current();
        _safeMint(owner, id);
        _setTokenURI(id, metadataURI);

        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message seems to be coming from other system than the Solidity contract. Please edit the question and show how you set up the mint offchain.

Comment: Look like the .glb file wasn't properly encoded into a File object, but there's no way to know for sure without seeing the code using nft.storage API.